# Select a directory by checking its name for date and time in Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

i have a batch file scripted which makes a backup of some of my mysql database tables and saves them in a new created folder with this pattern as name: "date_time" so as example "23.06.2016_1050".
So i have another batch file which imports every *.sql file in a specific folder back to my database.
What i want to do is, writing a batch which automaticly selects the latest folder and then runs my part of code in that.

Here is my batch code:

```
cd c:\server\backup\character_data
FOR %%X IN (*.sql) DO ECHO Importing %%X & "C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.1\bin\mysql" dspdb -h localhost -u root -p 123456789 < %%X
```

So i need to cd a %variable% which contains the name of the folder with the latest date and time pattern as its name.

So this:

```
cd c:\server\backup\character_data\%variable%
```

would be:

```
cd c:\server\backup\character_data\23.06.2016_1050
```

Does anyone knows how to get the desired folder name as variable somehow?

I really hope that i explained it good enough and someone can help me with that.
Thx in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get the most recent folder in `c:\server\backup\character_data` with the full file path, so no need to do `cd c:\server\backup\character_data\%variable%`, instead it would be `cd %a%`

If you don't want the full directory of the folder then remove the `/s` from the `dir` command

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\server\backup\character_data"
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /s /ad-h /t:c /od') DO SET a=%%i
::Do what you want with your folder, call it with %a%
```